How do get search filter data in es6
// Filter rows based on string values and exclude from whiteList
const whiteList = rows.map(sel => sel.RuleAutoID); // Array of IDs to exclude
console.log('whiteList', whiteList);

// Assuming you're getting the searchTerm dynamically from an input field
let searchTerm = $('.regulationData .mendix-react-material-table .MuiInputBase-input').val().toLowerCase();
console.log('searchTerm', searchTerm);

// Create a new array of objects without the RuleAutoID property
let filterRows = rows.map(({ RuleAutoID, ...rest }) => rest);
console.log('filterRows', filterRows);

const filteredData = filterRows.filter(item => {
    const values = Object.values(item).filter((v) => !(v === null || v === undefined || v === ''));
    console.log('values', values);

    return values.some(val => {
        console.log('val', val);
        return typeof val === "string" && val.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm);
    });
});

console.log('filteredData', filteredData);


I have removed null or undefined or empty values from the original data, but still somewhere it's failing, I don't know, might be a silly mistake I couldn't able to figure out.

Please create a [mre] and place any additional information (like your comment above) into your question using the [edit] button.

This is how my row data looks like
{ "Header 1": "value",
"Header 2": "",
"Header 3": "value",
"Header 4": "value",
"Header 5": "values",
"Header 6": "value",
"Type":  "Permissive"
"dummy":"",
"Apply to All": undefined
"Apply to Search": undefined}

if the 'val' is become empty, then filterData becomes empty

You can use filter() rather than using map() operator to exclude RuleAutoIDs. Make sure whenever the input value changes searchTerm gets updated. Finally, you can use to toLowerCase() and includes() to find substring matches in lowercase.
Refer to the code below:


const rows = [{
    RuleAutoID: 1,
    name: 'John Doe',
    age: 30
  },
  {
    RuleAutoID: 2,
    name: 'Jane Smith',
    age: 25
  },
  {
    RuleAutoID: 3,
    name: 'Mark Johnson',
    age: 35
  }
];
const whiteList = [2];

function displayFilteredData(filteredData) {
  const tbody = document.getElementById('filteredData');
  tbody.innerHTML = '';
  filteredData.forEach(row => {
    const tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.innerHTML = `<td>${row.RuleAutoID}</td><td>${row.name}</td><td>${row.age}</td>`;
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
  });
}

function setWhiteList() {
  const whiteListInput = document.getElementById('whiteList').value;
  whiteList = whiteListInput.split(',').map(id => parseInt(id.trim())).filter(id => !isNaN(id));
  console.log('whiteList', whiteList);
}

function setWhiteList(filteredData) {
  const tbody = document.getElementById('filteredData');
  tbody.innerHTML = '';
  filteredData.forEach(row => {
    const tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.innerHTML = `<td>${row.RuleAutoID}</td><td>${row.name}</td><td>${row.age}</td>`;
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
  });
}

function filterData() {
  const searchTerm = document.getElementById('searchTerm').value.toLowerCase();
  console.log('searchTerm', searchTerm);

  const filteredRows = rows.filter(row => !whiteList.includes(row.RuleAutoID));
  console.log('filteredRows', filteredRows);
  const filteredData = filteredRows.filter(row => {
    const values = Object.values(row).filter(val => val !== null && val !== undefined && val !== '');
    console.log('values for row', row, values);
    return values.some(val => {
      console.log('checking value', val, 'against searchTerm', searchTerm);
      return typeof val === 'string' && val.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm);
    });
  });

  console.log('filteredData', filteredData);
  displayFilteredData(filteredData);
}
document.getElementById('filterButton').addEventListener('click', filterData);
displayFilteredData(rows.filter(row => !whiteList.includes(row.RuleAutoID)));
.table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table th,
.table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
}
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Filter Data Sample</h1>
  <label for="searchTerm">Search Term:</label>
  <input type="text" id="searchTerm" placeholder="Enter search term...">
  <button id="filterButton">Filter</button><br>
  <h2>Filtered Data</h2>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>RuleAutoID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="filteredData"></tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>



